# Sort Dictionary of Dictionaries on multiple child dictionary values

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
myDict = {
    'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}
}
```

My goal is to sort this dictionary by the `site_location` and the `serial_num` of each of the child dictionaries.

Using code I found in this question - [Sort a dictionary of dictionaries python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10592480/sort-a-dictionary-of-dictionaries-python) - I was able to get it sorted, but it's not quite what I am expecting.

This is my code:

```
import pprint
items = ((k, k2, v) for k in myDict for k2, v in myDict[k].items())
ordered = sorted(items, key=lambda x:x[-1], reverse=False)
pprint.pprint(ordered)
```

This is the result I get:

```
[('ABC12346', 'site_location', 'Europe'),
 ('SER12345', 'site_location', 'North America'),
 ('SER12346', 'site_location', 'North America'),
 ('SER12347', 'site_location', 'South America'),
 ('ABC12345', 'site_location', 'South America'),
 ('ABC12346', 'serial_num': 'ABC12346'),
 ('SER12345', 'serial_num': 'SER12345'),
 ('SER12346', 'serial_num': 'SER12346'),
 ('SER12347', 'serial_num': 'SER12347'),
 ('ABC12345', 'serial_num': 'ABC12345')]
```

I was expecting something more like this though:

```
{
    'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}
    'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'},
}
```

The actual result is separating the serial number and site location. I want to keep them together in the sorted object. How can I do this?

Comment: The last snippet is not valid python - you cannot have keys in lists.

Comment: @thg435, you are right. That was lack of holding down shift. That is supposed to be a dictionary, but I'd be happy with anything ordered in that fashion. A list of tuples or similar is ok with me.

Comment: @Andy if you want sorted dictionary structure use OrderedDict as shown below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you wanted?

```
dicts = [{k: v} for (k,v) in myDict.items()]
dicts.sort(key=lambda d: (d.values()[0]['site_location'], d.values()[0]['serial_num'],))
```

Output for doing:

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(dicts)
```

is:

```
[{'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}},
 {'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'}},
 {'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'}},
 {'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'}},
 {'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'}}]
```

EDIT: I was going on your answer for the output format, but this would probably make more sense:

```
dicts = myDict.items()
dicts.sort(key=lambda (k,d): (d['site_location'], d['serial_num'],))
```

Output:

```
[('ABC12346', {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}),
 ('SER12345', {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'}),
 ('SER12346', {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'}),
 ('ABC12345', {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'}),
 ('SER12347', {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'})]
```

Comment: On the tuple example, how can I sort by the `site_location` instead of the serial number?

Comment: @Andy: oh, my mistake, edited it. it should have been `(d['site_location'], d['serial_num'])`, not `(k, d['site_location'], d['serial_num'])`

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries do not preserve order of items - hence can not be sorted. If you want an appearance of sorted dictionary, you need to make a sorted list and then insert it into OrderedDict class. Code snippet below illustrates this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

myDict = {
    'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}
}

def sortfun(d):
    return (d[1]['site_location'], d[1]['serial_num'])

skv = sorted(myDict.iteritems(), key=sortfun)
sorted_dict = OrderedDict(skv)

print sorted_dict
```

Comment: you can just return a tuple from `sortfun`

Comment: @Claudiu Good point - that looks much cleaner - updated above

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution with `cmp` (I think you must use that since we use a mix of 2 keys) but it's not really pretty, I guess it can be improved:

```
>>> pprint(sorted(myDict.items(), cmp=lambda x, y: cmp((x[1]['site_location'], x[1]['serial_num']), (y[1]['site_location'], y[1]['serial_num']))))
[('ABC12346', {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}),
 ('SER12345', {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'}),
 ('SER12346', {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'}),
 ('ABC12345', {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'}),
 ('SER12347', {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'})]
```

Comment: using `key` is much cleaner. all you're doing is essentially doing `cmp` on the two values that `key` would return, except the values don't get cached (as they do with `key`). The reason it works is that tuples get compared in the way you think they would, so if `key` returns a tuple, it compares multiple values.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> dic=myDict.items()
>>> dic.sort(key=lambda x:(x[1]['site_location'],x[1]['serial_num']))
>>> pprint.pprint([{k:v} for k,v in dic])
[{'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}},
 {'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'}},
 {'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'}},
 {'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'}},
 {'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'}}]
```