# Printing a dictionary after using sorted(dict.values(), ...)

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm attempting to print out a dictionary of dictionaries in Python 3.4. The dictionary is filled by a text parser that is parsing requirement text files. Each requirement (the keys) added to the dictionary has various values associated with it in the form of a dictionary, one of which is the `number`. I'm attempting to print the dictionary so that the keys are `sorted` by their number value. Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pprint
from operator import itemgetter
reqs = sorted(reqs.values(), key=itemgetter('number'))
pprint.pprint(reqs)
```

Unfortunately, using `sorted` in this way causes the `print` to only print the values of the dictionary, and so I get a list of dictionaries out in the end. It's been a few weeks since I wrote this code, but I recall searching SO for a good while and trying different variations of `sorted`. This was the first that printed out the values sorted by the `number` value, but I now realize that the value dictionaries are missing the keys.

I compare this print to what happens when I print the values without `sorted` below. You can see that with `sorted`, the values are in a list and missing their key.

Without `sorted` (yes it was coincidence that 3, 4, 5 were in order - they were the first three printed):

```
{'PROJ-UX-HLR-0003': {'category': 'UX',
                      'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                      'level': 'HLR',
                      'number': '0003',
                      'prefix': 'PROJ',
                      'repo': 'repo',
                      'text': 'This SHALL be the 3rd requirement.'},
 'PROJ-UX-HLR-0004': {'category': 'UX',
                      'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                      'level': 'HLR',
                      'number': '0004',
                      'prefix': 'PROJ',
                      'repo': 'repo',
                      'text': 'This SHALL be the 4th requirement.'},
 'PROJ-UX-HLR-0005': {'category': 'UX',
                      'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                      'level': 'HLR',
                      'number': '0005',
                      'prefix': 'PROJ',
                      'repo': 'repo',
                      'text': 'This SHALL be the 5th requirement.'}, # etc.
```

With `sorted`:

```
[{'category': 'UX',
  'file': 'app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
  'level': 'SYS',
  'number': '0001',
  'prefix': 'PROJ',
  'repo': 'repo',
  'text': 'This SHALL be the 1st requirement.'},
 {'category': 'UX',
  'file': 'app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
  'level': 'SYS',
  'number': '0002',
  'prefix': 'PROJ',
  'repo': 'repo',
  'text': 'This SHALL be the 2nd requirement.'},
 {'category': 'UX',
  'file': 'app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
  'level': 'HLR',
  'number': '0003',
  'prefix': 'PROJ',
  'repo': 'repo',
  'text': 'This SHALL be the 3rd requirement.'}, # etc.
```

Similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346111/sort-dictionary-of-dictionaries-on-multiple-child-dictionary-values), but his key is still hanging around, albeit in the wrong place.

Any help with printing the full, sorted dictionary of dictionaries is appreciated.

Comment: is the number always in the key like you have shown?

Comment: The number is always one of the values, and should always be in the key as well. The key is the 'name' of the requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `OrderedDictionary` using the sorted items of the original dictionary.

```
import operator, collections
number = operator.itemgetter('number')
item_one = operator.itemgetter(1)
def f(foo):
    return number(item_one(foo))
d = {'PROJ-UX-HLR-0005': {'category': 'UX',
                          'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                          'level': 'HLR',
                          'number': '0005',
                          'prefix': 'PROJ',
                          'repo': 'repo',
                          'text': 'This SHALL be the 5th requirement.'},
     'PROJ-UX-HLR-0003': {'category': 'UX',
                          'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                          'level': 'HLR',
                          'number': '0003',
                          'prefix': 'PROJ',
                          'repo': 'repo',
                          'text': 'This SHALL be the 3rd requirement.'},
     'PROJ-UX-HLR-0004': {'category': 'UX',
                          'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                          'level': 'HLR',
                          'number': '0004',
                          'prefix': 'PROJ',
                          'repo': 'repo',
                          'text': 'This SHALL be the 4th requirement.'}
     }
ds = sorted(d.items(), key = f)
od = collections.OrderedDict(ds)
```

Comment: I had looked at `OrderedDict` in the past but dismissed it (too quickly) because it looked at first glance that it wasn't 'actually' a dictionary. The syntax when using `print()`, `OrderedDict( ... )` instead of `{ ... }`, threw me off. It appears `od` is index-able like a dictionary as well. This seems to be exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: Why, exactly, is `f` required? Out of curiosity, I tried `key=number(item_one)` and it doesn't work. I've read through the `itemgetter` documentation as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried it first also. @Padraic Cunningham might know.

Answer (score 1):

Sort the `items` based on the number value to get keys and values returned

```
 sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]["number"])

In [2]: import pprint

In [3]: srt = sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]["number"])

In [4]: pprint.pprint(srt)
[('PROJ-UX-HLR-0003',
  {'category': 'UX',
   'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
   'level': 'HLR',
   'number': '0003',
   'prefix': 'PROJ',
   'repo': 'repo',
   'text': 'This SHALL be the 3rd requirement.'}),
 ('PROJ-UX-HLR-0004',
  {'category': 'UX',
   'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
   'level': 'HLR',
   'number': '0004',
   'prefix': 'PROJ',
   'repo': 'repo',
   'text': 'This SHALL be the 4th requirement.'}),
 ('PROJ-UX-HLR-0005',
  {'category': 'UX',
   'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
   'level': 'HLR',
   'number': '0005',
   'prefix': 'PROJ',
   'repo': 'repo',
   'text': 'This SHALL be the 5th requirement.'})]
```

Or as Rob suggests, use an `collection.OrderedDict`:

```
In [20]: srt = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]["number"]))

In [21]: pprint.pprint(srt)
{'PROJ-UX-HLR-0003': {'category': 'UX',
                      'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                      'level': 'HLR',
                      'number': '0003',
                      'prefix': 'PROJ',
                      'repo': 'repo',
                      'text': 'This SHALL be the 3rd requirement.'},
 'PROJ-UX-HLR-0004': {'category': 'UX',
                      'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                      'level': 'HLR',
                      'number': '0004',
                      'prefix': 'PROJ',
                      'repo': 'repo',
                      'text': 'This SHALL be the 4th requirement.'},
 'PROJ-UX-HLR-0005': {'category': 'UX',
                      'file': 'rm/app/parse/example_reqs.txt',
                      'level': 'HLR',
                      'number': '0005',
                      'prefix': 'PROJ',
                      'repo': 'repo',
                      'text': 'This SHALL be the 5th requirement.'}}
```

Comment: This seems to be as good as Python allows it to get. I'd seen similar code snippets on other questions and was hoping for a way for it to be displayed/returned as a dictionary.  I suppose I can use list indexing to fill a new dictionary, but whether or not that one will stay sorted remains to be seen.

Comment: `dict` objects, by definition, have no order. Perhaps you could use `collections.OrderedDict`? `srt = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1]["number"]))` might work.

Comment: @Illusion10, yes an OrderedDict is the only way you will get a dict that maintains  order .

Comment: Your answer was helpful, and the edit looks to be what I need, but @wwii answered before the edit, so I accepted his. Upvoted yours as well, though, as it shows another way to do it with `lambda` instead of `itemgetter`. Thanks!