# Sort python dictionary keys based on sub-dictionary keys by defining sorting order

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

My question is an extension to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346111/sort-dictionary-of-dictionaries-on-multiple-child-dictionary-values) where the OP has a dictionary, the one below, and wants to sort main keys based on the sub-dictionary keys

```
myDict = {
    'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}
}
```

The proposed (quoted below) solution works perfectly.

```
dicts = myDict.items()
dicts.sort(key=lambda (k,d): (d['site_location'], d['serial_num'],))
```

However this solution does sorting in ascending order for all (sorting in  descending order is straightforward). I was wondering if it is possible to define mix of sorting order, say `serial_num` in ascending but `site_location` in descending order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one solution, possible because list sorting is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability). I changed the data slightly to demonstrate that it works.

This method is also prescribed in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sorting.html#sort-stability-and-complex-sorts).

```
myDict = {
    'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'Europe'},
    'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'}
}

result = sorted(myDict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['site_location'], reverse=True)
result = sorted(result, key=lambda x: x[1]['serial_num'])

# [('ABC12345', {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'}),
#  ('ABC12346', {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'Europe'}),
#  ('SER12345', {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'}),
#  ('SER12346', {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'}),
#  ('SER12347', {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'})]
```

Comment: This is far easier than my plan to subclass a tuple and re-implement rich comparison methods to reverse sort on the second element and.....oh yeah, stable sorting is useful.

Comment: I would still love to see an aesthetic one-pass solution.

Comment: I'm not sure about "aesthetic," but I just posted a one-pass solution.

Comment: I'm a big fan of OOP solutions. They are grossly underused in python.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I can see that it is a nice variation to the original question's answer. @AdamSmith, most probably I am one of contributors to the under-use of OOP in python.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly need a custom sort order, then you can write a custom object with that sorting logic that will serve as a wrapper to the actual object underneath.

```
from functools import total_ordering
# total_ordering keeps you from having to write each of
# __gt__, __ge__, __lt__, __le__. It requires __eq__ and one of the
# other comparison functions to be defined and the rest are assumed
# in terms of each other.  (__ge__ = __gt__ or __eq__, __gt__ = not __le__), etc.

@total_ordering
class CustomSorter(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    # the properties here are solely to make the code a little more readable
    # in the rich comparators below. You can ignore them if you like.
    @property
    def serial_number(self):
        return self.data[1]["serial_number"]
    @property
    def site_location(self):
        return self.data[1]["site_location"]

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, CustomSorter):
            raise NotImplementedError("CustomSorters can only sort with themselves")
        return self.data[1] == other.data[1]

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, CustomSorter):
            raise NotImplementedError("CustomSorters can only sort with themselves")
        if self.site_location == other.site_location:
            return self.site_number < other.site_number
        else:
            return not (self.site_location < other.site_location)
```

Then use the traditional decorate-sort-undecorate steps.

```
myDict = {
    'SER12346': {'serial_num': 'SER12346', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'ABC12345': {'serial_num': 'ABC12345', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'SER12345': {'serial_num': 'SER12345', 'site_location': 'North America'},
    'SER12347': {'serial_num': 'SER12347', 'site_location': 'South America'},
    'ABC12346': {'serial_num': 'ABC12346', 'site_location': 'Europe'}
}
sorters = [CustomSorter(tup) for tup in myDict.items()]
sorters.sort()
result = [sorter.data for sorter in sorters]
```

This is probably best if you implement a function to sort it for you.

```
def sort_on(sorter, unsorted):
    """sort_on expects @sorter@ to be a class with rich comparison operations
    that is a decorative wrapper around some data to be sorted. Additionally,
    @sorter.data@ should refer to the underlying data structure.
    """

    decorated = [sorter(unsort) for unsort in unsorted]
    decosorted = decorated.sort()
    sorted = [decosort.data for decosort in decosorted]
    return sorted

result = sort_on(CustomSorter, myDict.items())
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution and your effort, it is much more elegant approach to the one-pass solutions. However the answer is far more practical than this, at least in the context of this question, I think.

Answer (score 2):

I think your approach of a single sort with a tuple is the most Pythonic, so I'd stick to that. If the values were all numeric, you could easily negate any of the tuple values to get a reverse order for that part of the key, but the issue here is that you want to negate a string, right? So let's solve that problem:

```
def str_to_neg_ords(s):
    return tuple(-ord(c) for c in s)
```

Now you can use this function as part of the key, to do a nested lexicographic sort:

```
sorted(myDict.values(),
       key=lambda d: (str_to_neg_ords(d['site_location']), d['serial_num']))
```